# How to CLOSE not HIDE a div on click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal window with an embeded video, this video plays but then once the mask (outer window) is clicked, the sound etc is still playing in the background.

This is the code:

```
//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});
```

I need the window to close not hide. I tried, .remove which works but then once another video is clicked the div has been removed completely and won't play.

HELP !

EDIT- I am using this jquery modal window:

http://www.queness.com/resources/html/modal/jquery-modal-window.html

Then im adding a iframe provided by the client to the "dialog".

Comment: You need to issue a command to whatever is playing the video to STOP THE PLAYBACK.  If hide/remove isn't cutting it for you.

Comment: Could you provide some more information about the player you're using and what the modal window looks like and how it is created. Please!

Answer (score 4):

`$('.window').remove()` is the only way to get rid of a div completely.

If you need the div again you'll have to recreate it, but that's not too difficult.

Or you could remove all the div's content with `$('.window').html ('');`

(edited to take account of something in the question I missed at first glance)

Comment: How do I reactivate it? I am using this jquery modal window: http://www.queness.com/resources/html/modal/jquery-modal-window.html

Comment: If you're using a modal window plugin, I'd recommend using a better one than that!  Try colorbox or similar.  They all have an API call for closing the window when you don't need it any more.